# Datatables server response not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I've got a problem regarding the server response by datables serverside processing. So far, the ajax call is working:

```
$('#result_tbl').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "search_synagogue_ajax.php",
    "aoColumns":[ 
                  { "sTitle": "Column1", "mData": "string" },
                  { "sTitle": "Column2", "mData": "stirng" }                    
                ],
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aaData, fnCallback ) {

        var countries = new Array();

        aaData.push({"name": "country", "value": countries});

        console.log(aaData);

        $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST", 
            "url": sSource, 
            "data": aaData, 
            "success": function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                 alert(err.Message);
            }
         });  
);
```

My response creation look like this:

```
$array = array(
    "aaData" => array(
        array(
            'test1',
            'test1',
        ),
        array(
            'test2',
            'test2',
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

And I get:

```
{"aaData":[["test1","test1"],["test2","test2"]]}
```

However, the table will not show the given testdata. Ajax success is called... I've noticed that some people claims that the curly brackets are not allowed in datatables < 1.8 (I'm using 1.9.4). Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Maybe I understand something wrong. What i want to do is post some parameters to the ajax file and then fetch it's response and insert it into my datatable? Do I have to do this manually in the ajax success callback?

EDIT2: Still can't get it working? Any suggests?

EDIT3: Tried a more simplier example, even without success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>clientAjax</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hist_data').on('click', function(){
            $('.myTable').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": false,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "serverAjax.php",
                "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
                "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    request = $.ajax({
                        "dataType" : "json",
                        "type" : "POST",
                        "url" : sSource,
                        "data" : aoData,
                        "success" : function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                        },
                        "error": function(xhr, status, error) {
                          var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                          alert(err.Message);
                        }
                    });
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "id" },
                    { "mData": "name" },]
            } );

        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>clientAjax</h1>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <p>
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </p>
      </nav>

      <div class="hist_data">Click here</div>
      <table class="myTable">

      </table>

      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Ajax file:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "aaData" => array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => "ONE"
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => "TWO"
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: what does firefox show in the console? This is likely a JS error.

Comment: I use chrome for debugging - Console gives me no errors and the success output to console looks right. I also tested for valid json format with JSONLint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself!

What i needed to do is to add:

```
fnCallback(data);
```

to the success callback and the data appears in the table!

Answer (score 0):

try to remove comma from last array item like this

```
$array = array(
"aaData" => array(
    array(
        'test1',
        'test1'
    ),
    array(
        'test2',
        'test2'
    )
)
```

);

echo json_encode($array);